# Does scaling Kafka Connect is same as scaling Kafka Consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

We need to pull data from Kafka and write into AWS s3. The Kafka is managed by separate department and we have access to only specific topic.

Based on Kafka documentation it looks like Kafka Connect is easy solution for me because I don't have any custom message processing logic.

Normally when we run Kafka Consumer we can run multiple JVM with same consumer group for scalability. The consumer JVM of specific consumer can run in same physical server or different. What would be the case when I want to use Kafka Connect?

Let's say I have 20 partitions of the topic.

How can I run Kafka Connect with 20 instances?

Can I have multiple instances of Kafka Connect running on the same physical instance?

Answer (score 4):

Kafka Connect handles balancing the load across all its workers. In your example of 20 nodes, you could have :  (for example)

- 1 Kafka Connect worker, processing 20 partitions
- 5 Kafka Connect workers, each processing 4 partitions
- 20 Kafka Connect workers, each processing 1 partition

It depends on your volumes and required throughput.

To run Kafka Connect in Distributed mode across multiple nodes, [follow the instructions here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode) and make sure you give them all the same `group.id` which identifies them as members of the same cluster (and thus eligible for sharing workload of tasks out across them). More config details for distributed mode [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide-dist-worker-config).

Even if you're running Kafka Connect on a single node, I would personally recommend running it in Distributed mode as it makes scale-out more simple (you just add additional nodes, but the execution & config remains the same).

I'm don't see a benefit in running multiple Kafka Connect workers on a single node. Each Kafka Connect worker can run multiple tasks, and connectors, as required.

Comment: How do you choose the number of nodes for the kafka-connect in distributed node? For example: if you are running it in Kubernetes, what is the metric to scale. CPU? Memory?

Comment: You scale it based on required throughput and whichever metric denotes a bottleneck. Some connectors might be network heavy, other CPU. It will depend, and you'll need to test it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that if you only have a single machine, you should only launch one kafka connect instance, and configure the `tasks.max` property to the amount of parallelism you'd like to achieve (in your example 20 might be good). This should allow kafka connect to read from your partitions in parallel, see the docs for this [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html).

You could launch multiple instances on the same machine in theory. It makes sense to do this if you need each instance to consume data from different topics. But if you want the instances to consume data from the same topic, I don't think doing this would benefit you. Using separate threads within the same process with `tasks.max` will give you the same if not better performance.

If you want kafka connect to run on multiple machines and read data from the same topic it is possible to run in [distributed mode](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide-distributed-config).

Comment: 20 is a random number? (You can make it sound like the documentation says that).  It's number of threads, so unless you have a good CPU, not all those will be active at once

Comment: Exactly, how do you choose the number of nodes for the Kafka-Connect in distributed mode?